# dependency problems, when updating

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libreoffice, dependencies

I have got a problem with dependencies and do now regret, that I have installed Ubuntu in german... Hope someone is able to help me anyway: Every time I try to update something I get several dependency error messages, I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I get several messages like the following from that:

```
> libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) wird eingerichtet ...
> update-alternatives: Warnung: Neuinstallation der Alternative
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf ist erzwungen, weil
> Linkgruppe x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf defekt ist update-alternatives:
> Fehler: »/etc/ati« kann nicht entfernt werden: Ist ein Verzeichnis
> dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
> (--configure):  Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript
> gab den Fehlerwert 2 zurück dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern
> Konfiguration von libreoffice-core:  libreoffice-core hängt ab von
> libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; aber:   Paket libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 ist noch
> nicht konfiguriert.   Paket libgl1 ist nicht installiert.   Paket
> libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64, das libgl1 bereitstellt, ist noch nicht
> konfiguriert.
> 
> dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes libreoffice-core
> (--configure):  Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert dpkg:
> Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von
> libreoffice-pdfimport:  libreoffice-pdfimport hängt ab von
> libreoffice-core; aber:   Paket libreoffice-core ist noch nicht
> konfiguriert.
> 
> dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes libreoffice-pdfimport
> (--configure):  Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert dpkg:
> Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von libreoffice-avmedEs
> wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da die Fehlermeldung darauf
> hindeutet, dass dies lediglich ein Folgefehler eines vorherigen
> Problems ist.
>                                                                                                   ia-backend-gstreamer:  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer hängt ab
> von libreoffice-core; aber:   Paket libreoffice-core ist noch nicht
> konfiguriert.
> 
> dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes
> libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (--configure): 
> Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert dpkg:
> Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von
> libreoffice-base-core:  libreoffice-base-core hängt ab von
> libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); aber:   Paket libreoffice-core
> ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
```

(Bad) Google translation:

```
    libgl1-mesa-glx: amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) is set up ... update-alternatives: Warning: Reinstall the alternative is enforced /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because Link Group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is defective update-alternatives: error: '/ etc / ati "can not be removed: If a directory dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx: amd64 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core: libreoffice-core depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however: Package libgl1-mesa-glx: amd64 is not configured yet. Package libgl1 is not installed. Package libgl1-mesa-glx: amd64, which provides libgl1, is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure): dependency problems - remains unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-pdfimport: libreoffice-pdfimport depends on libreoffice-core; however: Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-pdfimport (--configure): dependency problems - remains unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-avmedEs not apport report was written because the error message indicates that this is merely a consequence of failure of a previous problem is. ia-backend-gstreamer: libreoffice-Avmedia backend gstreamer depends on libreoffice-core; however: Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-Avmedia-backend-gstreamer (--configure): dependency problems - remains unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core: libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 1 : 4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however: Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
```

I have also tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

but the problems remain.

EDIT:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

gives the following:

```
> Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) ...
> update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group
> x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken update-alternatives: error: unable
> to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory dpkg: error processing package
> libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):  subprocess installed
> post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Setting up fglrx
> (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5) ... update-alternatives: warning: forcing
> reinstallation of alternative
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group
> x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken update-alternatives: error: unable
> to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory dpkg: error processing package
> fglrx (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script
> returned error exit status 2 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of openjdk-7-jre:amd64:  openjdk-7-jre:amd64 depends on
> libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:   Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is
> not configured yet.   Package libgl1 is not installed.   Package
> libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:  libreoffice-core depends
> on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:   Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
> is not configured yet.   Package libgl1 is not installed.   Package
> libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of python3-uno:  python3-uno depends on
> libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of libreoffice-math:  libreoffice-math depends on
> libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-math (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-impress:  libreoffice-impress
> depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-impress (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dev:  libgl1-mesa-dev depends on
> libgl1-mesa-glx (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) | libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic |
> libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid; however:   Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is
> not configured yet.   Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic is not
> installed.   Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid is not installed.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dev (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice:  libreoffice depends on
> libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.  libreoffice depends on
> libreoffice-impress; however:   Package libreoffice-impress is not
> configured yet.  libreoffice depends on libreoffice-math; however:  
> Package libreoffice-math is not configured yet.  libreoffice depends
> on python3-uno (>= 4.0~); however:   Package python3-uno is not
> configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of libreoffice-writer:  libreoffice-writer depends on
> libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-writer (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:  libreoffice-base-core
> depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-core (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-gnome:  libreoffice-gnome depends
> on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gnome (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-base:  libreoffice-base depends
> on libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-base-core is not configured yet.  libreoffice-base depends
> on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-sdbc-firebird: 
> libreoffice-sdbc-firebird depends on libreoffice-core; however:  
> Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
> (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
> dependency problems prevent configuration of
> libreoffice-report-builder-bin:  libreoffice-report-builder-bin
> depends on libreoffice-base; however:   Package libreoffice-base is
> not configured yet.  libreoffice-report-builder-bin depends on
> libreoffice-core; however:   Package libreoffice-core is not
> configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-report-builder-bin
> (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
> dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb: 
> libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb depends on libreoffice-core; however:  
> Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-pdfimport:  libreoffice-pdfimport
> depends on libreoffice-core; however:   Package libreoffice-core is
> not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-pdfimport (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer: 
> libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer depends on libreoffice-core;
> however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
> (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
> dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gtk: 
> libreoffice-gtk depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3);
> however:   Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gtk (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-drivers: 
> libreoffice-base-drivers depends on libreoffice-core; however:  
> Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-drivers (--configure):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-draw:  libreoffice-draw depends
> on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-draw (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
> prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:  libreoffice-calc depends
> on libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-base-core is not configured yet.  libreoffice-calc depends
> on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3); however:   Package
> libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-calc (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
> while processing:  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64  fglrx  openjdk-7-jre:amd64 
> libreoffice-core  python3-uno  libreoffice-math  libreoffice-impress 
> libgl1-mesa-dev  libreoffice  libreoffice-writer 
> libreoffice-base-core  libreoffice-gnome  libreoffice-base 
> libreoffice-sdbc-firebird  libreoffice-report-builder-bin 
> libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb  libreoffice-pdfimport 
> libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer  libreoffice-gtk 
> libreoffice-base-drivers  libreoffice-draw  libreoffice-calc
```

EDIT: Using

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

I get:

```
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  fglrx libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx openjdk-7-jre 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-7-jre:amd64:
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64 depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package fglrx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dev:
 libgl1-mesa-dev depends on libgl1-mesa-glx (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) | libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic | libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64
 fglrx
 libgl1-mesa-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package fglrx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-7-jre:amd64:
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64 depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dev:
 libgl1-mesa-dev depends on libgl1-mesa-glx (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) | libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic | libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 fglrx
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64
 libgl1-mesa-dev
```

but already the insallation of aptitude gave some error messages like, so I do not know if aptitude is working properly.

Comment: Just run the command again after having run `LANG=C`, `LANG=C` will temporarily disable the localization.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: can you [edit] your post with the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` if there is any.

Comment: @Neil: have added the output and used LANG=C before, as recommended.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Doing this I end up with very similar error messages.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @Zacharee1 : I have tried 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' and posted the output above. The problems remain.

Comment: Does 'sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-core' do anything?

Comment: Are you able to `sudo apt-get install aptitude`? You can try using `aptitude install -f` to see if a more aggressive approach will work.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Using `sudo apt-get install aptitude` some error messages appear, although aptitude seems to work. I have edited what I've got  from aptitude install -f above.

Comment: @Tobias : no that does not help. most of the packages of libreoffice are uninstalled now, but the problems remain.

Comment: Can you sudo apt-get remove the remaining packages?libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 fglrx
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64
 libgl1-mesa-dev (this will uninstall your graphics driver, but it should switch to another one)

Comment: Try what @tobias said and tell us the outcome, but don't do @ anyone so we both get it

Comment: I have tried `sudo apt-get remove libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64, fglrx, openjdk-7-jre:amd64, libgl1-mesa-dev` the output was: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx
E: Unable to locate package fglrx,
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-7-jre
`

Comment: The :amd64 is part of the package name. So type in the whole name.

Comment: @Tobias: Which package do you mean, haven't I done this in the command above?

Comment: @DonkeyKong: You're right, I misread it. Do you get 'Unable to locate package' if you run sudo apt-get update first? What does your /etc/apt/sources.list look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is what I thought:

```
Fehler: »/etc/ati« kann nicht entfernt werden: Ist ein Verzeichnis
```

In english:

```
error: unable to remove '/etc/ati': Is a directory
```

So most likely this is in the update-script

```
rm /etc/ati
```

istead of

```
rm -r /etc/ati
```

So what I did was:

```
sudo mv /etc/ati /etc/ati_
sudo touch /etc/ati
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It worked!

Comment: You've saved my day! I have exactly done what you said: `sudo mv /etc/ati /etc/ati_; sudo touch /etc/ati; sudo apt-get upgrade`.  Would it be bad to delete the folder `/etc/ati_` by `rm -r /etc/ati`?

Comment: I did delete ati_ too and had no problems yet. Just to be safe you may consider to keep it.

Comment: I had the same success repairing a mangled install with `mv /etc/ati /etc/ati_; touch /etc/ati;  apt-get upgrade`.